Next.js API Route: Updated Comment Object Not Persisting to Database
I am having troubles making post request from Next js to wordpress db to update comments fields ({ likes_count: 0, dislikes_count: 0 }). Here is the code.
      import { NextApiResponse } from "next";
      import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

      // Helper function to fetch comment details by ID from WordPress API
      async function fetchCommentDetails(commentId: number) {
        const response = await fetch(
          `http://localhost:10028/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/${commentId}`
        );
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch comment details");
        }
        return await response.json();
      }

      export async function POST(req: Request) {
        if (req.method === "POST") {
          const data = await req.json();
          console.log(data); /// { commentId: 1, actionType: 'increment' }

          try {
            const { commentId, actionType } = data;

            if (!commentId || !actionType) {
              return NextResponse.json({
                error: "Missing commentId or actionType in request body",
              });
            }
            const currentComment = await fetchCommentDetails(commentId);

            // Extract current counts from fetched comment data
            const currentLikesCount = currentComment.meta.likes_count || 0;
            const currentDislikesCount = currentComment.meta.dislikes_count || 0;

            // Update counts based on actionType
            let updatedLikesCount = currentLikesCount;
            let updatedDislikesCount = currentDislikesCount;

            if (actionType === "increment") {
              updatedLikesCount += 1;
            } else if (actionType === "decrement") {
              updatedDislikesCount += 1;
            }

            // Update the comment's likes_count and dislikes_count
            const updatedComment = {
              ...currentComment,
              meta: {
                ...currentComment.meta,
                likes_count: updatedLikesCount,
                dislikes_count: updatedDislikesCount,
              },
            };
            console.log(updatedComment); // THE DATA DOES GET UPDATED for example "meta: { likes_count: 1, dislikes_count: 0 }"

            // Respond with the updated comment data
            Response.json(updatedComment);

            return Response.json({ message: "Succes" });
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error updating comment action:", error);
            Response.json({ error: "Failed to update comment action" });
          }
        } else {
          Response.json({ message: "Method Not Allowed" });
        }
        return Response.json({ message: "Nothing !" });
      }

Everything working fine within Comments components , and the route does recive valid commentId and actionType like this { commentId: 1, actionType: 'increment' }. Updated comment does get updated as well when i hit increment btn { likes_count: 1, dislikes_count: 0 }, but it seem it does not getting written in wordpress db.
